# How to count number of disabled columns in a table from javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

My table format is

```
<table class"tabletop">
    <tr>
        <td>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td id="mycol1"></td>
                <td id="mycol2"></td>
                <td id="mycol3"></td>
                <td id="mycol4"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have to count columns(having id's) that are not disabled(or their display is not none) and that are disabled.
Suppose columns disabled are 4 and not disabled are 2.
So it must return disabled: 4 and not disabled: 2

td's are disabled by their id.
eg

```
mycol1.style.display="none";
```

Comment: Where is your javascript code? Did you try something or just expect us to make your job? How do you mark your td as disabled?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried and clarify what you need slightly. You want to select this table (by id or class or element) and then find all TDs that have an ID (or will they all have one) and return how many are disabled and not disabled or do you want the function to return the id's as well?

Comment: @MarkWalters I am selecting this table by class and then it has to return only the number i.e count of disabled and not disabled

Comment: When you say "disabled", you mean specifically "with `display:none`", right? _"Suppose columns disabled are 4 and not disabled are 2"_ - But your example only has a total of 4 columns, so shouldn't the count of disabled plus enabled equal 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working Solution try this

```
  <script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">

     function getHiddenColumnCount() {
         var tbl = document.getElementById("myTbl");
         var HiddenColumnCount = 0; 
         for(var OuterCounter = 0 ; OuterCounter < tbl.rows.length ; OuterCounter++)
         {
             for(var InnerCounter = 0 ; InnerCounter <                    tbl.rows[OuterCounter].cells.length;InnerCounter++)
            {
                if (tbl.rows[OuterCounter].cells[InnerCounter].style.display == "none")
                HiddenColumnCount++;
            }
         }
         alert("There are " + HiddenColumnCount + " Hidden Columns in Table");
      }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$('table td:visible').length
```

Comment: Oh ok.Can you give class say something like 'disabled' to the hidden tds?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [fiidle](http://jsfiddle.net/x5nEU/)

```
<table border="1" id="myTbl">
        <tr>
            <td class="mycol1">
                1
            </td>
            <td class="mycol2">
                2
            </td>
            <td class="mycol3">
                3
            </td>
            <td class="mycol4">
                4
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script>
        function hideColumn(columnClass) {
            var els = document.getElementsByClassName(columnClass);
            for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
                els[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
        hideColumn('mycol1');
        hideColumn('mycol2');

        function getHiddenColumnsCount() {
            var rows = document.getElementById('myTbl').rows;
            var count = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
                    if (rows[i].cells[j].style.display == "none")
                        count++;
                }
            }
            alert(count);
        }
        getHiddenColumnsCount();
    </script>
```

First of all you should use class for defining column instead of id as id should not be duplicate & to define a column we will have to give similar id to all cells of a column.